# Flipping SKSpriteNode not working on all versions of iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have been using an iPhone running iOS 9.2 for testing purposes. To flip the sprite node, have been setting the xScale of the sprite node to -1. This works on my iOS 9.2 device, but when I test it on a device running iOS 9.0, it doesn't flip the sprite at all. How should I go about achieving the same effect that is supported across all iOS versions?

Comment: I believe this was a bug on Apples part, which is why it doesn't work on 9.0

Comment: Best bet to avoid this bug, is to just create a flipped texture.  This answer is in objecive c, but can be converted to swift easily.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162853/horizontally-mirror-a-skspritenode-texture